# MySql empty result set returns different formats

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, null, bluehost

I am trying to execute two simple select queries on two different tables in mysql server. This I am doing this by running a php script. Both the queries are supposed to return an empty result set. But they are returning different formats.

City table is returning a simple null value where as Dealer table is returning all columns with null values.

**Output:**

```
{**"dealer"**:[{"car_make":null,"state":null,"city":null,"company_name":null,"company_address":null,"phone":null,"mobile":null,"fax":null,"email":null,"website":null,"Data_Version":null}],**"city"**:null}
```

**PHP Script**

```
<?php

$data_version = 5;

require 'DbConnect.php';


$query = ("SELECT * FROM `Dealer` WHERE `Data_Version` > $data_version");


if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)){

    while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)){

        $out [] = $query_row;

    }

}
else{
    echo 'Fail';
} 


$query1 = ("SELECT * FROM `City` WHERE `Data_Version` > $data_version");


if ($query_run1 = mysql_query($query1)){

    while ($query_row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run1)){

        $out1 [] = $query_row1;

    }

}
else{
    echo 'Fail';
} 


$Output=array('dealer'=>$out,'city'=>$out1); 

    echo(json_encode($Output));

?>
```

So due to the varying formats i am not able to handle it. What is the reason for such varying formats? What should I do to have same kind of results??

**Table Schemea**

Dealer table
"car_make","state","city","company_name","company_address","phone","mobile","fax","email","website","Data_Version"

City Table

city, state, Data_Version

(All fields are Varchar(50) )

**Output of printing**

Array ( [dealer] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [car_make] => [state] => [city] => [company_name] => [company_address] => [phone] => [mobile] => [fax] => [email] => [website] => [Data_Version] => ) )[city] => )

Comment: You should stop using the deprecated mysql library in favor of mysqli.

Comment: Maybe table city contains only one column

Comment: @cuewizchris or PDO ofcourse...

Comment: @cuewizchris: it is not feasible to change it right now.. I will do it in future

Comment: Please post tables schema's

Comment: btw. `SELECT *` is considered bad practice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful

Comment: @RoyalBg : so it would only contain the data_version column then? Strange kind of table. Agree with Fabio, let's see the schemas.

Comment: please have a look at the table schema..

Comment: $out1 is not defined. The strange thing is that $out is not defined, too. You should do `$out = array();` and `$out1  = array();` at the beginning. And you should do `print_r` or `var_export` instead of `echo json_encode(..` for debugging! Maybe it went something wrong during encoding

Comment: ok i will define both the arrays..

Comment: Sounds like the Dealer table has a row with all null values

Comment: but I am echoing json array not for debugging but to get the array in android app

Comment: @tlenss none of the tables have rows with null values

Comment: if dealar table has relations on city.city and city.state, why don't you use one query with join and explicitly name the columns

Comment: @tlenss but why Data_Version is null? By the way it would be better to use the correct cases, its a capital D and V in Data_Version

Comment: @RoyalBg Both the table are unrelated

Comment: @Pooja can you post the result of `print_r($Output);` please?

Comment: I have edited my question.. please have a look

Comment: It doesn't send empty array. It send false result for me. Did you try a query without condition? Or `Data_Version` > '$data_version', or var_dump($query_run1), to see if it's false?

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible due to two reasons:-

There is no row that match your query in city table so it return null value.

In case of dealer table it might be returning a row in which all values are currently null.

Please check!

Comment: No i checked.. there are no rows with null values in the table